# Angular app file/folder structure running on IISNode IIS 7 server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows, iis, iis-7

So I am having an issue running my app. It runs, but because of my folder structure, it is not running the way it should. Basically the header and footer render, but no view and none of the css is right. As shown in the attached image, my file/folder structure has app folder alongside my node_modules and bower_components folders and when calling the index.html whereas the local URL would normally be localhost/#/home and in this case, servername:port/app/index.html, it doesn't render correctly.

I have searched through tutorials, but figure it is something to do with how I am setting my physical path in comparison to the actual path. So how can I make this work within IIS 7 with the folder heirarchy shown as it is in the image?

[image]

Thanks much.

Here is the web.config as asked about. Fairly straight forward:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can anyone provide anything on this?

Comment: I presume that your static files are in app folder - that means that you have to tell IIS how to serve that content. Can you share your web.config file with us?

Comment: Also check this blog post : http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2012/05/yaml-configuration-support-in-iisnode.html    especially the part about web.config and routing the static content.

Comment: Bring that this is an internal test location, the web.config is simple. Is posted above in edit. Additionally, if using iisnode.yml, can I leave the default and where does it actually go? Also, do I actually need a server.js file? Thanks much!